# linphone set_log_handler error in python

Tags: python, linphone

I want to integrate video, audio calling features with my python/django project for which i'm using the `linphone` python library. There is a code on the website https://pythonhosted.org/linphone/getting_started.html#installing-the-python-module.

I've followed the every step at which first i installed linphone using sudo pip command and after importing it into a script as "import linphone" it throws an error that "cannot import name version" which i solved by entering the libphone in dist-packages and commented the second line of `__init__.py` file.

Now the problem is that it throws me an error that `linphone module has no attribute set_log_handler` and if i comment this line it throws me an error that libphone module has no attribute Core.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a previous version. I am currently using Linphone 3.9 and I don't have this problem. I have notice some bugs with newer versions, but not had a problem with the set_log_handler.

http://linphone.org/releases/linphone-python/linphone-3.9.1.linux-x86_64-py2.7.zip